# Onlyoffice in manjaro

Tags: manjaro

I install from GUI package in Manjaro. And after start I get

```
/opt/onlyoffice/DesktopEditors: /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /opt/onlyoffice/libascdocumentscore.so)
```

And

```
/opt/onlyoffice/converter/x2t: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /opt/onlyoffice/converter/x2t)
```

**Update**

After update manjaro to 16.10 no changes

Comment: Same right here, right now. From what I searched, it means that our version of libcurl-gnutls is LOWER than the one the application is trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install libcurl. Or wait for a new version, where the problem is fixed (about two or three weeks)

Comment: How I can get new version of libcurl now?

Comment: @Nadya Knyazeva : Problem persisting.